# Sending data from a UIlabel from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have two view controllers

**DetailViewController**

**BlogViewController**

I have a 'push' set-up on the storyboard with the identifier 'ShowBlog'

i need to send the title of the blog from the UILabel below on the **DetailViewController**:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
```

to a UILabel on the **BlogViewController** called BlogTitleLabel:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *BlogTitleLabel;
```

i know i need to use:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowBlog"]) {

        // Im struggling with the code

    }
}
```

But im struggling with the code to go in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` the code goes something like this:

**Store the title:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:label.title forKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Retrieve the stored title:**

```
 NSString *storedTitle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere"];
```

After that you're free to use the title as you please

Comment: Yes you can use user defaults to pass information, but that is a bit of a blunt instrument. User defaults writes to disk. That is slow compared to memory-based information passing, and shortens the life of the flash drive. If you want the value to persist between runs of the application then it is a very good choice, but it's not a good fit for data that isn't persistent.

Comment: I have made tons of apps using this method. there is nothing slow about this way with super fast apple devices these days.

Comment: In reality, the limit is only practical if you are writing large amounts of data, but for a simple piece of text? there should be next to no performance difference.

Comment: Lots of data, or rapid communication. This is disk-based communication, which is significantly slower than memory-based communication. For handing a small amount of data between view controllers it's not enough of a difference to be a problem, but disk IO is at least an order of magnitude slower than RAM, even flash-based disk.

Answer (score 2):

`prepareForSegue` is called before destination VC's `viewDidLoad` so don't try to access any view object of destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`. Its better you create a string property in destination and set that in `prepareForSegue` method. In destination viewController's  `viewDidLoad` set it to `label`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not  try to send data from label to label. Labels are view objects. They display information and collect input from the user. They do not store information.

Also, you should never, ever try to manipulate another view controller's views directly. That violates the other view controller's encapsulation.

Both view controllers should have NSString properties for this. Let's call it blogTitle on both VCs.

Your DetailViewController should set it's blogTitle somewhere during it's setup, and then in viewWillAppear:animated, display that value to it's titleLabel outlet:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: animated;
{
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  self.titleLabel.text = self.blogTitle;
  //your other code here
}
```

Then, in your prepareForSegue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowBlog"]) 
  {
    BlogViewController *theBlogController = [segue destinationViewController];
    theBlogController.blogTitle = self.blogTitle; //Pass the blog title to the other VC
  }
}
```

And then in the BlogViewController's viewWillAppear, copy the blogTitle to it's title label:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: animated;
{
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  self.titleLabel.text = self.blogTitle;
  //your other code here
}
```

Note that Cocoa/iOS programming has strong naming conventions that you should follow. Only filenames and class names should start with a capital letter. Method names, instance variable names, and property names should start with a lower-case letter. So your TitleLabel should be titleLabel, and BlogTitleLabel should be blogTitleLabel.